# Making a search box responsive with Media Queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

So far, this is my code. I want it to drop under my logo which is on the left to it, when i make the screen smaller. Thanks in advance guys!

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px){

    #wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #Search{
    width:40em;
    height: 3em;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:640px)
{

    #Search{
    width:100%;

}
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shiny Science</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <img id="mainLogo" src="images/mainlogo.jpg">
        <select id="Select">
            <option value="0">Menu</option>
            <option value="1">Home</option>
            <option value="2">Contact Us</option>
            <option value="3">About Us</option>
        </select>

    </header>
<main>
    <h1>Shiny Science</h1>
    <p id="description">Metusque innabilis, aestu manebat cum cuncta grandia sectamque iuga recessit cuncta. Metusque innabilis, aestu manebat cum cuncta grandia sectamque iuga recessit cuncta</p>
    <div id="searchbox">
    <img src="images/monkey.jpg" id="secondaryLogo" alt="logo maybe">
    <input type="text" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Topic Name" id="Search" ><input type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search" id="searchButton">
    <img src="images/turtle.png" alt="somethingkidscience" id="secondaryLogo2">
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <div id="ep1">
    <h2>Episode 1</h2>
    <p class="caption">Metusque innabilis, aestu manebat cum cuncta grandia sectamque iuga recessit cuncta</p>
    <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3s7UWpo35s?autoplay=1"><p>Your browser doesn't support iframe</p></iframe>
</div>
<div id="ep2">
    <h2>Episode 2</h2>
    <p class="caption">Metusque innabilis, aestu manebat cum cuncta grandia sectamque iuga recessit cuncta</p>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3s7UWpo35s"><p>Your browser doesn't support iframe</p></iframe>
</div><br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">View all episodes</a>
</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry guys, I have updated this now there is the html and css i'm using

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em; 
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow) repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

main,footer,header{
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.caption{
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

#ep1, #ep2{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}

#wrapper{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background: linear-gradient(cyan,red);
}

#secondaryLogo{
    width: 15%;
}
#searchbox{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}

#Search{
    width:40em;
    height: 3em;
}

#contactHeader{
    padding-top: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    overflow:auto;
}

h1, #description{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}


input[type=text], textarea{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}

input[type=submit]{

}

#searchButton{
    height: 3em;
}


#mainLogo{
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

#secondaryLogo2{
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
}

#us{
    width: 10%;
}

label{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 35%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

select{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}


#contactForm{
    width: 49%;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    float: left;
    height: 30%;
}
#contactMethod{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

@media screen and (max-width:959px){

    #wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #Search{
    width:40em;
    height: 3em;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:640px)
{

    #Search{
    width:100%; 
    height:150px;
    float:left;
}


img {
  width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}

}
```

I've been trying different things with the queries, but right now the only thing that works is the wrapper changes when i make my screen smaller.

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Without seeing your HTML this is a shot in the dark but... try and make your logo and the search box become display: block when screen width goes below the breakpoint.

Comment: @ecg8 Sorry I am pretty new on here. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this, and only this, inside your @media screen and (max-width:640px) section:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px)
{
    #searchbox { display:block }
    #secondaryLogo { display:block; width:auto }
}
```

You have to stop #searchbox from being a flexbox in order to get the child divs to display as blocks, or else they continue to display as flex children. I see lots of other problems in your code when your screen width gets that small, but this is the only one you asked anyone to solve :)